# How to build a login using AWS IAM with javascript SDK?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-iam, aws-sts

need to use

- AWS IAM
- nodejs
- AWS STS service

need to

- register user
- authenticate user
- authorize user

and also need to know what are the best ways to do that using AWS services.is it better to use aws cognito?

expected- sample codes

Comment: Yes, cognito...

Answer (score 1):

We have this use case documented in the Photo Asset Manager (PAM) example app. In this example, the client is a REACT app that performs user authenication with Cognito. See this high level illustration:

[image]

Sample client app with a **sign in** button:

[image]

You can deploy the entire solution following the instructions located in the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html) topic here:

[Create a photo asset management application that lets users manage photos using labels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cross_PAM_java_2_topic.html)

See this Github location for the sample REACT client:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/resources/clients/react/elros